# Esav and Yosef the lahava

Tags: yosef, amalek, esav

The gemara says in Bava Basra 123b that Yosef is the lahava and "sitno shel Esav" and the one who befells Esav as the posuk says "bais Yosef lahava".

The same person says in midrash Tanchuma Vayichi that all from Rochel are the fall of Esav derived from a different posuk.

So is Yosef in this way more than Binyamin?

What does "lehava" add? and if it adds is it only adding it to Yosef?

The torah says Yakov waits till Yosef is born (see gemara). How can it help Yakov if Yosef is only a child?

What actually did happen the one time Esav met his nemesis
Yosef?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that all of Rachel's kids are the nemesis of Esav/Amalek. Yaakov waited for Yosef because he didn't need both. Binyamin's children are equal to Yosef (and are even all named after him [[Rashi Gen 43:30](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.43.30.1)]). Binyamin's descendants fought and attempted destroying Amalek. First Shaul with King Agag ([I Shmuel 15:3-8](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.15.3-8)) then Mordechai with Haman the Agagite ([Esther 3:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.3.1), [8:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.8.11)).

The one time Yosef actually met Esav, he bowed down to Esav ([Breshit 33:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.33.7)). The [Ramban (Breshit 49:31)](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Genesis.49.31.1) quotes Yosifon that on the way back from burying Yaakov, Yosef quarreled and fought with Esav's grandchild, Tzefo, captured him and his troops and took them as slaves.

Comment: ok.   so why the same reb shmuel saying it in two places from different posukim ?

Comment: And is it possible little toddler yosef will fight with esav ?

Comment: In one place it's asking why Yaakov left when Yosef was born. The second place it's saying that Binyamin is also the nemesis of Esav. Both need their own pesukim. It obviously does not mean that Yosef will physically fight Esav right now as he is a baby but in a metaphysical sense.